# Chrono timer always displays 0

Tags: c++, sorting, timer

so I am woking on timing a sort algorithm, when i run my code no matter what it always displays 0, but if i use breakpoints it works here is the part of my code where i am using the timer:

```
case 'I':{ 
  auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //start the clock
  numbers.InsertionSort();//sorts the array using insertion sort method
  auto endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();//ends the clock
  cout<<"Insertion Sort of size: "<<numbers.GetSize()<<" took: "  
      <<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(endTime-startTime).count() 
      <<" Millisecond"<<endl; //ouput the result to the screen
  break;//exit
}
```

i tried using the standard timer but it wasnt giving me enough precision, so i went to the chrono timer. My teacher wants us to output the result in milliseconds. so thats why i am using that time period

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. Are you sure the sort takes any milliseconds to complete?

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be important, but: 1) Is this the high-resolution clock from C++11 `std::` or the one from the boost library? 2) What platform?

Comment: the high res clock is the one from chrono and i am running windows 7 64 bit.